# Revoke access to downloadable product after refund in 2.2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, downloadable, magento2.2.6, refund

I was wondering if there's a built-in way to remove a customer's access to download links for a digital product after issuing a refund. I realize they could have downloaded the file within that time, and I'm okay with that, but I'd prefer not to allow them to continue downloading.

If this isn't built into the core, I'm open to learning how I could implement this. Though I'm new to Magento, I have written a couple of modules to get my store working the way I want it to, so I'm not afraid to get my hands a little dirty :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it looks like the links were in fact expired after issuing the refund. For some reason, it took a little while for me to see the changes in My Account.